# Responsive layout distorting images

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am having a problem on Liferay 6.2 GA2 where I have some web content portlet with a simple image, the problem is when I view my page on a small device or resize the browser window my image gets distorted, the width of the image changes but the height doesn't.

Any ideas on how I would force the image size to change proportionally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A "quick fix" to this problem was to remove the "height" css entry in the web content source of the image.

It seems that Liferay responsive implementation adjusts the width of images when a small screen size is detected but does not adjust the height, I wonder if this is a bug or a feature.